# Socket.io client shows Err:Empty response when many sockets are connected

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io

When many sockets join, The server randomly throws Err:Empty response, to the browser. This even happens for the static files being served by node.

I use node v5.6 and nginx v1.8 and socket.io v1.4.5. No Special implementation of socket.io and NodeJS. I use sockets behind nginx through reverse proxy. After more than 400 connections it starts throwing empty response error. I found a similar open issue at [github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1925](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1925).

Any step towards it would be a help.

Comment: Can you add `node` and `nginx`versions and perhaps a script to create an example? Any special server configuration? How do you use `socket.io`?

Comment: I use node v5.6 and nginx v1.8 and socket.io v1.4.5. No Special implementation of socket.io and NodeJS. I use sockets behind nginx through reverse proxy. After >400 connections it starts throwing empty response error. I found a similar open issue https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1925, Any step towards it would be a help.

Comment: @HardeepMehta try to optimize Your nodejs code, seems like enormous memory management (keeping sockets in array or etc) makes memory leaks that it lose the socket connection descriptor. Also have You extended worker connections in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ? have You checked open files limit via "ulimit -a" ?  try to optimize system parameters that shown in this post: https://www.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/

Comment: @num8er I have made The limit of open files to unlimited, Also I do not know about extending worker connections in nginx.conf, Can you suggest me something?

Comment: @HardeepMehta open /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and You'll see: http://joxi.ru/Rmzvv1uWe9MbmO  just extend number to something big.

Comment: @num8er Great, Will update it and tell you how it goes. Anyways, Apart from this, Can the memory leak inside socket.io be a problem even now? I have seen many threads ending up with saying Change to some other framework instead of socket.io.

Comment: @HardeepMehta everything depends on how You write the code. I would be nice to put socket.io implementation code in question. Maybe we could find the leaks. Socket.io itself works well enough.

Comment: Hey, I changed it to 1024, But still the problem persists, Now It gives 500 internal server error more often. How to solve this!

Comment: can You send place somewhere Your app's socket part?